# Is it possible to create a visualization like this in WebGL?

Tags: html, webgl, data-visualization

This visualization is created using Away3D (Flash):
www.guardian.co.uk/world/interactive/2011/mar/22/middle-east-protest-interactive-timeline

**Would it be possible to create something of the same quality (re. interaction, animation, performance, pixel-perfection etc.) using WebGL?**

Bonus: How would one set up the basic scene? (without interaction and animation)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be. The scene is not complex at all, so it would have good performance. Interaction, yes, depends how you implement it, but if you are doing project with, for example, Three.js it wouldn't be a problem. Pixel perfection, obviously, yes.

In the scene, you could have curved plane, with texture that is changing UVs of vertices when you use 'navigate'. Pins could be done with particle, or better, simple quads with transparent textures. To have pixel-precise pin picking, you could depth-test pins on ray trace, or use pin-shaped geometry with shader, which probably the best solution.

So, basic scene - curved plane with per-vertex-changing-UV, pin-shaped and texture pins.

- - - 

Alternatively, you could do exactly the same thing with 2D canvas. All elements are just drawn and scaled, text would be much simpler, and picking would be with 2d calculations.

Hope this helps.